# Instantiating Image: Inheritance, separated classes or other?

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm developing an application in JAVA SE, with a database in SQL Server.

In this application, I will have three kinds of images:

- First Aid Symbols
- Danger Symbols
- EPIs Symbols

**All** the images have the following attributes:

- `imageID - int`
- `imageDescription - String`
- `image - ImageIcon`

Thus, the Fist Aid and the EPIs images need this attribute:

- `isUsedInRiskAssessment - boolean`

My question: what is the best approach to implement this structure?

**Inheritance: (image in the link)**

http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/6871/inheritance.png

I know inheritance is many times called 'evil', but seems like a valid option in this case, except for having a subclass without any other attributes.

**Separated Classes:**
http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/511/separated.png

Or other?

In my business layer, I want to be able to return all the images (no matter wich type), to the GUI.
I also tought of having a class `Image` and another class called `ImageType`. But in this scenario, the `Image`, when the `ImageType` is *Danger Symbols*, would have a non used attribute - the `isUsedInRiskAssessment`.

This also affects the way I'm going to create the tables in the database.

Hope I've explained myself clear. Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Inheritance is not bad here. But sometimes it would be necessary to write code which would determine the actual type and to do casting, - you won't like the code you'll get.
That is why I'd suggest having sometimes unused `Boolean` property. Actually, three values: `true`, `false` and `null` are what you need. But make sure you mention meaning of null value in your documentation.

Comment: I have followed your suggestion, by making the attribute `isUsedInRiskAssessment` a `Boolean`. And by reading Stephan comment, I also thought it was the best to have a Enum (nested Enum inside the Image class), indicating what is the type of the image. Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes unused Boolean property with `true`, `false` and `null` is definitely a bad practice. What if you will have to add a new type? Than you will have to rewrite the whole code. **Don't ever do this**

Comment: Thank you, @Tomas, it is very significant to consider this.

Answer (score 1):

In this case inheritance is a good way how to implement this. But I think it would be good to create a subclass with `isUsedInRiskAssessment` like this:

```
class Image {
    private int imageId;
    private String imageDescription;
    private ImageIcon image;

    ...
}

// I can't come up with a proper name right now
class ImageChild extends Image { 
    private boolean isUsedInRiskAssessment;

    ...
}

Image firstAidImage = new ImageChild();
Image epiImage = new ImageChild();
Image dangerImage = new Image();
```

You really want to avoid writing classes which are completely the same, only of a different name - so the second option is the *evil* one.

Comment: Thanks @Tomas. It's a good answer, but there is one problem: I need to keep track of type of image I'm dealing with. In the administration module of my GUI, the user will see all the images, and I need to know it's type. This is also valid for when the user wants to upload a new image to the database, as I need to give it some kind of `ImageType`.

Comment: @Pedro Maybe you can use the Visitor pattern for that http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class `AbstractImage` which implements the interface `IImage`. For declaring fields, only the interface is used. I would create one extended class for `FirstAidImage` and `EPIImage`. If you really need to distinguish both, implement an `ImageType` enum, but do not implement different classes that are exactly the same. For `DangerImage` create a class that extends `AbstractImage` and provides the additional attribute.